# My Linked List (with generics) program compiles fine, but when I run it I am getting a class not found exception. Can someone help me?

Tags: java

I am trying to run my linked list in a main method, but for some reason I keep getting the following output from my terminal

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PhoneBook/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PhoneBook.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Below I have listed the part of my class where I run the main method. Everything compiles fine, but when I run it I get that exception. Is there away I can try/catch the exception? Or is there something I am doing wrong?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

 public class PhoneBook<T> extends LinkedList<T>{

  /**
  * Creates two books, adds a person to each book, then prints out if it
  * found the perons in the book.
  **/
  public static void main(String[] args){
    PhoneBook<String> bookOne = new PhoneBook<String>();
    PhoneBook<Integer> bookTwo = new PhoneBook<Integer>();

    bookOne.addPerson("Obama");
    System.out.print(bookOne.findPerson("Obama"));

    bookTwo.addPerson(192590594);
    System.out.print(bookTwo.findPerson(192590594));
  }
```

If more information from my class is needed, I can provide it. I don't think it should be necessary because it compiled fine.

Comment: After you compile your program where do the class files reside? Are they in the directory you are trying to run your program from.

Comment: If all programs had to do was compile correctly, we CompSci bods would not have invented the term "runtime error" :-)

Comment: After compiling with `javac PhoneBook.java` are you launching it using `java PhoneBook` or `java PhoneBook.java` ? (it should be the former not the latter).

Comment: Do you use any framework to run this? The code code you have provided is not complete. This block looks perfectly fine, if `addPerson()`/`findPerson()` are implemented correctly.

Comment: [OT]: If you want a PhoneBook, extending `LinkedList` is not a good idea, instead, holding a private LinkedList instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After compiling with javac PhoneBook.java are you launching it using
>   java PhoneBook or java PhoneBook.java ? (it should be the former not
>   the latter). ~Charlie

Thanks Charlie, that was it.